# jQuery - Imitate Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to imitate an anchor click when a user clicks on the containing `<TD>` but having problems.

This is the JS part:

```
$('contactTab').click(function() {
    $('contactTabLink').trigger("click");
});
```

And this is the HTML part:

```
<td class="previewTabs" id="contactTab">
<a class="previewTabLink" id="contactTabLink" rel="#contactOverlay">CONTACT</a>
</td>
```

When somebody clicks the `<TD>` contactTab, it should trigger a click event on `<A>` contactTabLink which then launches an Overlay. My problem is that the JS function with click listener is NOT firing at all.

Can anybody see where I am going wrong?

EDIT 1:

I have changed the selectors to have #'s but it still won't fire the function.

Comment: `$('contactTab')` will try to find an element with tag `contactTab`. You want the [ID-selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/). Triggering the click event won't make the browser follow the link though.

Comment: Yeah, you're missing the "#" in front of the IDs in your jQuery selectors. Use $('#contactTab'). and not $('contactTab')

Comment: where's the click listener defined for `$('contactTabLink')`?  You have the click being triggered, but I don't see any listener defined for it, so there's no action to take on a click event.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your selector is not correct.

It should be this:

```
$('#contactTab').click(function() {

   $('#contactTabLink').trigger('click');

});
```

Comment: Your second line is still missing the #

Answer (score 1):

Your selectors are wrong.
You need `#` for ID selectors.

Answer (score 1):

Your selectors are wrong - you're using id's so you should have a '#' in front.

```
$('#contactTab').click(function() {
   $('#contactTabLink').trigger("click");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think something to notice here, with the way your html is formatted, `$('#contactTabLink').trigger("click")` will cause `$('#contactTab').click` to fire since it is a parent of `#contactTabLink`, thus causing an infinite loop of recursion. Some browsers will print an error to the console or simply not respond. You could arrange your html accordingly to avoid this:

```
<td class="previewTabs" id="contactTab">
  <a href="javascript:;" class="previewTabLink">CONTACT</a>
</td>
<a class="previewTabLink" id="contactTabLink" rel="#contactOverlay"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

After adding hashes (#) to the selector, make sure that function is wrapped in $(document).ready(function() { yourFunction })...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contactTab').click(function() {
        $("#contactTabLink").trigger("click");
    });
});
```